# Python: Error in saving concatenated data to CSV

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I need to add a column to an existing CSV file. So I am opening the file, concatenating the column to it and trying to save it back. But I get error:

```
 TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e')
```

The code I am using is:

```
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(file)
dataset = dataframe.values
labels_col=numpy.zeros((len(dataset),1))
dataset=numpy.concatenate([dataset,labels_col],axis=1)
numpy.savetxt(file.strip('.csv')+'labelled.csv',dataset)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formate specifier and delimiter as described in documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

```
numpy.savetxt('labelled.csv',dataset, fmt='%s',delimiter=',')
```